# OneSignal: Send Push Notification to one user only

Tags: php, android, mysql, push-notification, onesignal

I want when a user likes another user's post this user must receive a notification in Android. PHP code:

```
include("settingsDB.php");

$user_id=$_POST["userid"];
$post_id=$_POST["postid"];


if(...user likes a post...){

  $add=mysqli_query($conn,"insert into liked_posts(post_id,user_id,time) values('$post_id',$user_id,'$time')");

  sendMessage($user_id);

  $result->success=true;
  echo(json_encode($result));
}

function sendMessage($useridparam) {
  $content      = array(
    "en" => 'User with id: '.$useridparam.' liked your post.'
  );

  $fields = array(
    'app_id' => "xxx",
    'included_segments' => array(
        'All'
    ),
    'data' => array(
        "foo" => "bar"
    ),
    'contents' => $content
  );

  $fields = json_encode($fields);

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Authorization: Basic XXX'
  ));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
  ...other properties...

  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  return $response;
}
```

When I use this code it sends notifications to all users because of `'included_segments' => array('All')`. So how I put only one user_id from database to here ? In OneSignal docs it can be done with `include_player_ids` but this is according to devices not users.

Regards

Comment: @Dharman I'm beginner in PHP and this code is only for demo. So I just wanna send notification to an user.

Comment: As a beginner it is even more important that you lear how to do it properly. I don't know where you got an idea to do it like this but this code is broken. Please learn how to do it with prepared statements. Here is a good article: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: @Dharman actually I'm only Android developer. This code isn't for a real app. As I said this is only demo and I just want to learn how to send notification to an user.